# Travelling slit in double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, double-slit-experiment

In the double slit experiment, the interference pattern depends on the wavelength of the light. But if I run at the light source really fast shouldn't the light blue shift and hence cause a different interference pattern. This is weird to me, because of the principle of relativity.

Comment: Haven't really worked it out, but I think this effect is canceled out by the fact that the length between the slit and screen is contracted.

Comment: Please can you add more detail to your query. Do you mean that the slits are moving toward the source? Why it is a different interference pattern "weird because of the principle of relativity"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, in this case you move the source and the slits and the screen are "at rest". 
I think, that you can say either that source is in motion or slits and screen are in motion. Interference pattern will be the same.

If source is "in motion", source's clock dilates at Lorentz factor. That means, blueshift will be a bit less blue than it should be in classical case.

If slits and screen approach source, gap between slits and screen Lorentz contracts. It leads to the same interference pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Blue light has a different (tighter) diffraction pattern than red light. So if you move the slit experiment toward the light source very fast it will blue shift and change (shrink/tighten) the pattern.